# About irreducible subgroups of $GL(V)$, $V$ a vector space of infinite dimension

Tags: group-theory

Let $F$ be a field, let $V$ be a $F$-vector space, let us say that a subgroup $G$ of $GL(V)$ is irreducible if $V > 0$ and there is no $G$-invariant subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $0 < W < V$.

If I'm not wrong, D.J.S. Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups, 8.1.5, p. 219, implies what follows : if $F$ is an algebraically closed field, if $V$ is a $F$-vector space with finite dimension, if $G$ is an irreducible subgroup of $GL(V)$, if $h$ is a $F$-endomorphism of $V$ commuting with every automorphism in $G$, then $h$ is scalar, i.e. there exists an element $f$ of $F$ such that $h$ is the multiplication by $f$.

Could anybody give a counterexample in the case where the dimension of $V$ is infinite (if such a counterexample exists) ? In other words, could anybody give an example of the following situation : $F$ is an algebraically closed field, $V$ is a $F$-vector space with infinite dimension, $G$ is an irreducible subgroup of $GL(V)$, $h$ is a $F$-endomorphism of $V$ commuting with every automorphism in $G$ and $h$ is not scalar ?

If I'm not wrong, $G$ must be infinite and cannot be cyclic. Now, life is short, so I prefer not to spend time on an already solved question. Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: It may be easier to formulate this as looking for an infinite dimensional irreducible (and faithful though that is not as important here) representation of some group which has a non-scalar endomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more standard language you are asking whether [Schur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma) holds for infinite-dimensional irreducible representations. It continues to hold in the following form:

> If $G$ is a group and $V$ is an irreducible representation of $G$ over a field $F$, then $\text{End}_G(V)$ is a division algebra over $F$.

If $V$ is finite-dimensional and $F$ is algebraically closed, the only such division algebra is $F$ itself, so we get the more typical statement of Schur's lemma. But this fails once either of these conditions is relaxed.

Explicitly, even if $F$ is algebraically closed, you can take $V = F(t)$ and $G = F(t)^{\times}$ acting on $V$ by left multiplication. Then $V$ is irreducible (and infinite-dimensional, despite the fact that $G$ is abelian!), and $\text{End}_G(V) \cong F(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

At least in the context of Banach spaces, continuous group actions and closd invariant subspaces, the answer is negative. Namely, there are invertible bounded operators $T: B\to B$ of Banach spaces without proper closed invariant subspaces (Enflo, Read, et al), see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem) for the references. Now, take the group $G$ generated by $T$. Such group commutes with $T$ itself which is not a scalar operator. I am not sure if you ask a purely linear algebra question without continuity assumptions and closedness requirement for a subspace.

Comment: Yes, my question is purely linear-algebraic. But your answer is not without interest, of course.

Comment: Just as a remark, here it is important to look at closed invariant subspaces only. For example, for such $T$ we still have that for all $x$, the subspace generated by $\{ T^n(x) : n \geq 0 \}$ is $T$-invariant. If $x \neq 0$ and $B$ is infinite-dimensional, then this is a proper nontrivial subspace. This follows since an infinite-dimensional Banach space has uncountable dimension as a vector space.

Comment: @spin: Yes, of course.