# Definition of an irreducible subgroup, and how to tell if any subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(p)$ is irreducible

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm not entirely sure what the proper definition of an "irreducible subgroup". I want an intuitive definition  what an irreducible subgroup is in the simplest, most pedagogical terms as reasonably possible.

As a secondary question, I also want to know how to tell if any given subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(p)$ (the complete group of linear automorphisms of an $n$-dimensional vector space over a finite Galois field of prime order $p$) is irreducible.

I don't know how to read any of the academic papers on the subject. They either have a payment lock, or have confusing notation that look like a foreign language to an average ungraduate student.

Comment: The question and answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910676/about-irreducible-subgroups-of-glv-v-a-vector-space-of-infinite-dimension) may get you started.  Then the English Wikipedia article on [irreducible representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation#Reducible_and_irreducible_representations) (and the part defining notation preceding the bookmark) may be of further use.

Comment: Irreducible = only subspaces of the vector space stabilized by $G\leq \mathrm{GL}(V)$ are $0$ and $V$.